# belongsToMany returning a duplicated data

Tags: php, laravel

I need to return just one OptionGroup if it has the same Id

these two options have the same group, however I wanted that in the part that returned the option_groups just returned one because the ids are the same

[image]

as you can see he returns me an array that has the same id

[image: option group repeat the Ids]

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;


use App\Criteria\Products\NearCriteria;
use App\Criteria\Products\ProductsOfFieldsCriteria;
use App\Criteria\Products\TrendingWeekCriteria;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Repositories\CustomFieldRepository;
use App\Repositories\ProductRepository;
use App\Repositories\UploadRepository;
use Flash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use InfyOm\Generator\Criteria\LimitOffsetCriteria;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use Prettus\Repository\Exceptions\RepositoryException;
use Prettus\Validator\Exceptions\ValidatorException;

/**
 * Class ProductController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\API
 */
class ProductAPIController extends Controller
{
    /** @var  ProductRepository */
    private $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var CustomFieldRepository
     */
    private $customFieldRepository;
    /**
     * @var UploadRepository
     */
    private $uploadRepository;


    public function __construct(ProductRepository $productRepo, CustomFieldRepository $customFieldRepo, UploadRepository $uploadRepo)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->productRepository = $productRepo;
        $this->customFieldRepository = $customFieldRepo;
        $this->uploadRepository = $uploadRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the Product.
     * GET|HEAD /products
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new ProductsOfFieldsCriteria($request));
            if($request->get('trending',null) == 'week'){
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new TrendingWeekCriteria($request));
            }else{
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new NearCriteria($request));
            }

//            $this->productRepository->orderBy('closed');
//            $this->productRepository->orderBy('area');
            $products = $this->productRepository->all();

        } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified Product.
     * GET|HEAD /products/{id}
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        /** @var Product $product */
        if (!empty($this->productRepository)) {
            try{
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
            } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
                return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
            }
            $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
        }

        if (empty($product)) {
            return $this->sendError('Product not found');
        }

        return $this->sendResponse($product->toArray(), 'Product retrieved successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created Product in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $customFields = $this->customFieldRepository->findByField('custom_field_model', $this->productRepository->model());
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->create($input);
            $product->customFieldsValues()->createMany(getCustomFieldsValues($customFields, $request));
            if (isset($input['image']) && $input['image']) {
                $cacheUpload = $this->uploadRepository->getByUuid($input['image']);
                $mediaItem = $cacheUpload->getMedia('image')->first();
                $mediaItem->copy($product, 'image');
            }
        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->sendResponse($product->toArray(), __('lang.saved_successfully', ['operator' => __('lang.product')]));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified Product in storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($product)) {
            return $this->sendError('Product not found');
        }
        $input = $request->all();
        $customFields = $this->customFieldRepository->findByField('custom_field_model', $this->productRepository->model());
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->update($input, $id);

            if (isset($input['image']) && $input['image']) {
                $cacheUpload = $this->uploadRepository->getByUuid($input['image']);
                $mediaItem = $cacheUpload->getMedia('image')->first();
                $mediaItem->copy($product, 'image');
            }
            foreach (getCustomFieldsValues($customFields, $request) as $value) {
                $product->customFieldsValues()
                    ->updateOrCreate(['custom_field_id' => $value['custom_field_id']], $value);
            }
        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->sendResponse($product->toArray(), __('lang.updated_successfully', ['operator' => __('lang.product')]));

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified Product from storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($product)) {
            return $this->sendError('Product not found');
        }

        $product = $this->productRepository->delete($id);

        return $this->sendResponse($product, __('lang.deleted_successfully', ['operator' => __('lang.product')]));

    }

}
```

ProductModel

```
<?php
/**
 * File name: Product.php
 * Last modified: 2020.04.29 at 17:43:30
 * Author: SmarterVision - https://codecanyon.net/user/smartervision
 * Copyright (c) 2020
 *
 */

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media;

/**
 * Class Product
 * @package App\Models
 * @version August 29, 2019, 9:38 pm UTC
 *
 * @property \App\Models\Market market
 * @property \App\Models\Category category
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Option
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Nutrition
 * @property \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection ProductsReview
 * @property string name
 * @property double price
 * @property double discount_price
 * @property string description
 * @property double capacity
 * @property boolean featured
 * @property double package_items_count
 * @property string unit
 * @property integer market_id
 * @property integer category_id
 */
class Product extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait {
        getFirstMediaUrl as protected getFirstMediaUrlTrait;
    }

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'market_id' => 'required|exists:markets,id',
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:categories,id'
    ];

    public $table = 'products';
    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'discount_price',
        'description',
        'capacity',
        'package_items_count',
        'unit',
        'featured',
        'deliverable',
        'market_id',
        'category_id'
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'image' => 'string',
        'price' => 'double',
        'discount_price' => 'double',
        'description' => 'string',
        'capacity' => 'double',
        'package_items_count' => 'integer',
        'unit' => 'string',
        'featured' => 'boolean',
        'deliverable' => 'boolean',
        'market_id' => 'integer',
        'category_id' => 'double'
    ];
    /**
     * New Attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'custom_fields',
        'has_media',
        'market'
    ];

    /**
     * @param Media|null $media
     * @throws \Spatie\Image\Exceptions\InvalidManipulation
     */
    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 200, 200)
            ->sharpen(10);

        $this->addMediaConversion('icon')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 100, 100)
            ->sharpen(10);
    }

    /**
     * to generate media url in case of fallback will
     * return the file type icon
     * @param string $conversion
     * @return string url
     */
    public function getFirstMediaUrl($collectionName = 'default', $conversion = '')
    {
        $url = $this->getFirstMediaUrlTrait($collectionName);
        $array = explode('.', $url);
        $extension = strtolower(end($array));
        if (in_array($extension, config('medialibrary.extensions_has_thumb'))) {
            return asset($this->getFirstMediaUrlTrait($collectionName, $conversion));
        } else {
            return asset(config('medialibrary.icons_folder') . '/' . $extension . '.png');
        }
    }

    public function getCustomFieldsAttribute()
    {
        $hasCustomField = in_array(static::class, setting('custom_field_models', []));
        if (!$hasCustomField) {
            return [];
        }
        $array = $this->customFieldsValues()
            ->join('custom_fields', 'custom_fields.id', '=', 'custom_field_values.custom_field_id')
            ->where('custom_fields.in_table', '=', true)
            ->get()->toArray();

        return convertToAssoc($array, 'name');
    }

    public function customFieldsValues()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\CustomFieldValue', 'customizable');
    }

    /**
     * Add Media to api results
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getHasMediaAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hasMedia('image') ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     **/
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     **/
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Option::class, 'product_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     **/
    public function optionGroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\OptionGroup::class,'options');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     **/
    public function productReviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ProductReview::class, 'product_id');
    }

    /**
     * get market attribute
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo|object|null
     */
    public function getMarketAttribute()
    {
        return $this->market()->first(['id', 'name', 'delivery_fee', 'address', 'phone']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     **/
    public function market()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Market::class, 'market_id', 'id');
    }


}
```

OptionGroup Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;

/**
 * Class OptionGroup
 * @package App\Models
 * @version April 6, 2020, 10:47 am UTC
 *
 * @property string name
 */
class OptionGroup extends Model
{

    public $table = 'option_groups';



    public $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required'
    ];

    /**
     * New Attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'custom_fields',

    ];

    public function customFieldsValues()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\CustomFieldValue', 'customizable');
    }

    public function getCustomFieldsAttribute()
    {
        $hasCustomField = in_array(static::class,setting('custom_field_models',[]));
        if (!$hasCustomField){
            return [];
        }
        $array = $this->customFieldsValues()
            ->join('custom_fields','custom_fields.id','=','custom_field_values.custom_field_id')
            ->where('custom_fields.in_table','=',true)
            ->get()->toArray();

        return convertToAssoc($array,'name');
    }



}
```

Option Model

```
<?php
/**
 * File name: Option.php
 * Last modified: 2020.04.29 at 10:45:05
 * Author: SmarterVision - https://codecanyon.net/user/smartervision
 * Copyright (c) 2020
 *
 */

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia\HasMediaTrait;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media;

/**
 * Class Option
 * @package App\Models
 * @version April 6, 2020, 10:56 am UTC
 *
 * @property \App\Models\Product product
 * @property \App\Models\OptionGroup optionGroup
 * @property string name
 * @property string description
 * @property double price
 * @property integer product_id
 * @property integer option_group_id
 */
class Option extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait {
        getFirstMediaUrl as protected getFirstMediaUrlTrait;
    }

    public $table = 'options';



    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'price',
        'product_id',
        'option_group_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'image' => 'string',
        'description' => 'string',
        'price' => 'double',
        'product_id' => 'integer',
        'option_group_id' => 'integer'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'nullable|numeric|min:0',
        'product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
        'option_group_id' => 'required|exists:option_groups,id'
    ];

    /**
     * New Attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'custom_fields',
        'has_media'

    ];

    /**
     * @param Media|null $media
     * @throws \Spatie\Image\Exceptions\InvalidManipulation
     */
    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 200, 200)
            ->sharpen(10);

        $this->addMediaConversion('icon')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 100, 100)
            ->sharpen(10);
    }

    public function customFieldsValues()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\CustomFieldValue', 'customizable');
    }

    /**
     * to generate media url in case of fallback will
     * return the file type icon
     * @param string $conversion
     * @return string url
     */
    public function getFirstMediaUrl($collectionName = 'default',$conversion = '')
    {
        $url = $this->getFirstMediaUrlTrait($collectionName);
        $array = explode('.', $url);
        $extension = strtolower(end($array));
        if (in_array($extension,config('medialibrary.extensions_has_thumb'))) {
            return asset($this->getFirstMediaUrlTrait($collectionName,$conversion));
        }else{
            return asset(config('medialibrary.icons_folder').'/'.$extension.'.png');
        }
    }

    public function getCustomFieldsAttribute()
    {
        $hasCustomField = in_array(static::class,setting('custom_field_models',[]));
        if (!$hasCustomField){
            return [];
        }
        $array = $this->customFieldsValues()
            ->join('custom_fields','custom_fields.id','=','custom_field_values.custom_field_id')
            ->where('custom_fields.in_table','=',true)
            ->get()->toArray();

        return convertToAssoc($array,'name');
    }

    /**
     * Add Media to api results
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getHasMediaAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hasMedia('image') ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     **/
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     **/
    public function optionGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\OptionGroup::class, 'option_group_id', 'id');
    }


}
```

Comment: The snippet marked 'Controller' looks like a piece of code that would usually be placed in a model. Can you show the code where you retrieve the option groups? Also, for clarity please remove any code unrelated to this question.

Comment: sry , that is not my area.I m really lost on it. I've already read the Laravel documentation and get the basic, but that code is very complex and I cant solve that problem.I edited the post, sorry if it has codes unrealated , cause idk what is related

Comment: Indeed, Laravel can be challenging. The JSON arrays at the top, where in your code do you print them?

Comment: it is together with the product model, it prints the product that has a lot of relationships ,as I understand it I can call them through the url with a "parameter with = 'options; optionGroups;'"

Comment: Please take a look at the `unique()` Collection function, shown [here in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-unique). This might be of use.